# spring-boot+thymeleaf: Cannot initialize: no template resolvers have been set

Tags: spring, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf, resolver

I start recently a new spring-boot project which uses thymeleaf as template resolver. I already use this combo in another projects with success, but with this last one I am getting this error:

```
Cannot initialize: no template resolvers have been set
```

after I start the project and try access any view. My pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>hello</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>org.hello.Application</start-class>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

My file application.properties is this:

```
# jdbc.X
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hello
spring.datasource.username=kleber
spring.datasource.password=123

# hibernate.X
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

I also try run the project without the last block (like the sample code from official repository: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content.git, but the same error occurs.

the project I started is this: https://github.com/klebermo/hello.

Anyone can see what's wrong here? I am really stucked here.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot and try to work around it. Your thyme leaf configuration is wrong, your resolver is only partially configured. Instead of creating your own extend the one that Spring Boot already provides. Just add the additional dialect as beans to your context, spring boot will take care of the rest.

Comment: how i can extend the one spring-boot already provides? the thymeleaf configuration you mentioned is the ThymeleafConfig class? I need the configuration in the application.properties?  I try this in other projects and worked. I can't figure what the problem with this current project.

Comment: Because you aren't using Spring Boot, I answered earlier questions of yours and you seem to use something and the first thing you do is to not use it or work against it. You only want some additional dialects, just create those as 2 `@Bean` methods and remove all the other stuff.